# Automatically Indent the Last Line of a Statement a Prescribed Amount

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, horizontal-spacing, shift, noindent

Consider the code,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\large
\noindent\textbf{How to Automatically Indent the Second Line of This Statement a Prescribed Amount---Say 15pt?}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Question: What may be an expedient way to indent the last line (second line in this case) of a multi-lined statement a prescribed amount---say 15pt, here?

Thank you.

Comment: See https://www.ctan.org/topic/text-flow. What should happen if indenting causes the last line to exceed the line width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define and use the macro `\indentlast`:

```
\def\indentlast#1#2{\par
   \setbox0=\vbox{%
      \parfillskip=#1 plus1fil \relax
      \noindent #2\par
   }%
   \ifdim\prevdepth>-1000pt \kern-\prevdepth\kern1ex \fi
   \unvbox0
   \setbox0=\lastbox
   \nointerlineskip\moveright#1\box0
}

\indentlast{15pt}
   {This macro indents the last line of the paragraph. 
   How to Automatically Indent the Second Line of This Statement 
   a Prescribed Amount---Say 15pt?}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.

Comment: The most interesting bit is that `\setbox0=\lastbox` literally removes the last line written.